# How can I solved this issue in my layout: "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I have a ToolBar and ViewPager im my layout, but I'm receiving a error in first line of ViewPager.
What's wrong with my viewPager?

the error that appears is "**error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix**".

The Layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/br.com.pixells.simuladorbr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/toolbarListaJogos"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#DC143C"
  app:subtitle="Teste"
  app:theme="@style/Theme.Abar.Widget"
  app:title="ToolBar" />
    
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/pager"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >  
  
  
    
<!--  
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page  
titles for adjacent pages.  
-->  
    
   <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip  
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="top"  
    android:background="#33b5e5"  
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"  
    android:paddingTop="4dp" 
    android:textColor="#fff" />  
  
    
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the "tools" prefix for an attribute in your ViewPager without declaring an XML namespace in the root.

Add

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to your LinearLayout to fix the issue.